# Compilation does not work

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I have the same problem as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106444/texmaker-no-pdf-output-and-no-error-message) link. But I do not understand that do I need an additional TeX compiler after installing TexMaker? If yes, MiKTeX is for Windows so, is there any compiler for Linux?

Answer (score 3):

[Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) is only [one of many editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764) available in the TeX World. It merely provides a user interface to construct your document elements, which will eventually require a back-end (not typically shipped with the editor) to typeset the document.

From the [Texmaker online documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html):

> Texmaker can't compile your documents if the paths to the LaTeX
>   related commands are wrong.

To that end, you can [download the TeX Live distribution from TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) (or another, like [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/) or [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/)). Once downloaded, make sure the distribution is [up-to-date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764), since some packages may have been updated since the linked release above. Finally, [configure Texmaker to use it properly](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02).